# kotlin, unit test how to assert a class constructor is not public

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, constructor

converting java to kotlin, it has a java package level visibility class

```
class NotificationManager extends Base {

    NotificationManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ... ...
    }
```

the unit test to assert this constructor is not public

```
    @Test
    public void verify_Constructor() throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        Constructor<NotificationManager> constructor = NotificationManager.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class);
        constructor.newInstance(application);
        assertFalse(Modifier.isPublic(constructor.getModifiers()));
    }
```

after convert kotlin, it is turned into internal visibility

```
internal class NotificationManager internal constructor(context: Context) : Base(context) {...}
```

but the test failed at `assertFalse(Modifier.isPublic(constructor.getModifiers()));`.

In unit test how to assert a kotlin internal class constructor is not public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kotlin reflection to get the KVisibility of the constructor and check that.

```
@Test
public void verify_Constructor() {
    KClass<?> kClass = JvmClassMappingKt.getKotlinClass(NotificationManager.class);
    boolean hasPublicConstructor = kClass.getConstructors().stream()
            .map(KFunction::getVisibility)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull) // package-private and java-protected are null
            .anyMatch(kVisibility -> kVisibility.equals(KVisibility.PUBLIC));
    assertFalse(hasPublicConstructor);
}
```

Comment: got error `KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime.`, and with `testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.21"`

Comment: worked, thx! even without the `testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.21"` dependency.